# Twilio Rest Api: sending multiple MediaUrl

Tags: curl, twilio

I was wondering if someone could help me.

I am trying to use twilios' REST API via curl to send a message with multiple MMS attachments.

The documentation states "please provide multiple MediaUrls values in the POST request".

Does this means that that parameter MediaUrls - or the parameter is still MediaUrl. Or it is MediaUrl0, MediaUrl1 as on receive.

Does anybody has an example how the curl command like should look like to send multiple attachments?

Answer (score 2):

You simply add multiple parameters with the same name mediaUrl.If you look at the source code of Twilio's helper libraries, that's exactly what they are doing.
If you would like you could prove it by using one of the helper libraries to send a mms with multiple media url's and looking at the Twilio logs of the API calls and it will even display as CURL for you